# event.relatedTarget is null on focusout on touch screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, focusout

I want to use focusout on a textarea, stash the value of the clicked button which caused the focusout, and click it later, after some processing. My solution works well on all devices except iPhone and iPads. Can anyone explain why the event.relatedTarget is null on touch screens? Or is it the browser? What else is there to use?

I have tried e.currentTarget and document.activeElement (returns the whole HTML body) as well as trying setTimeout around my use of e.currentTarget. I can't seem to get the ID of the clicked button inside my focusout, on iPads and iPhones.

Here's a sample:

```
<div id="resultPage">
  <textarea id="txtAnswer0" class="txtAnswer"></textarea>

  <button id="goNow">
    GO
  </button>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {


  $("#resultPage").on("focusout", ".txtAnswer:not(input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox])", function(e) {

     var targetCtrl = e.relatedTarget;

     alert(targetCtrl);
  });
```

});

Here is my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/awebster28/6q6ok4re/25/

Answer (score 1):

In my research I learned `relatedTarget` is only supposed to be on mouse events. If `relatedTarget` isn't null in a non-mouse event then the browser isn't following standards.

You'll probably have to temporarily store the button, and/or button value in a variable on click so it can be used later with the second click.